# How to store multi parameters in a list?

Tags: java, list, set, key, unique

I want to know how can I save different parameters related to one Key in a single list.

For example imagine I have a list of people who have a **name**, a **family name**, a **salary** and a **Key** to find any unique person in the list.

What can I use to store these information in single list?

What are structures that I can use? Like **List**, **Array List**, **Hash Map**, **Map**, **Set** etc.

Do I have to define a new class?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're looking for. Different parameters related to one key in a single list? Lists in Java don't have "keys", they only have elements with no attached values. Do you mean a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: It is something like saving data of a table which contains unique values in a structure like a list.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably define a Person class having all the properties you mentioned. Then you can store the people in a `Map<Integer,Person>` or `Map<String,Person>`, depending on whether the unique identifier of a Person is an `Integer` or a `String`.

If you use the `HashMap` implementation of `Map`, you'll be able to locate a `Person` by its identifier key in expected constant time.

Comment: If there is any good reason why you can't create a Person class as suggested by @Eran, then maybe you can use a "map of maps" e.g. `Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>`. You would then put the properties of person in the "nested" map under the right keys. The integer in the "outer" map would represent the unique person identifier.

The only reason I can imagine for wanting to do it this way though is if you need the properties to easily grow and shrink at runtime.

Comment: So there are no data structures in java providing storage of different variables in a single Map?

Comment: My code is a little dazzling and I don't want to make it more confusing. I wanted to see if there where any solutions for this problem in java classes in order to prevent duplicate class definition and time waste. I have become a little bit lazy these days.

Comment: @Sparrow7000 The `Object` class can represent a variety of different variables (i.e. `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean`), so you could use a map with the set type of `Object` if you want different variables in the same map. This pattern is generally not recommended though, since it will cause problems if you try to accidentally interpret some class as a different class etc.

Comment: @GitahiNg'ang'a can you provide little bit technical info about the two approaches mentioned by you and sir Eran, i mean in terms of cost and time

Comment: @SSH, creating a Person object is the more straightforward and cleaner approach. I believe it would be the desirable way to do this in a vast majority of the cases. Using a map of maps is more cumbersome, but would still work if flexibility is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map where a person would be a Person class with the attributes you talked about and the key would be a String that identifies each Person entity.

Then, you could just do something like:

```
Map<String,Person> peopleMap = new Map<String,Person>();
Person person = new Person(); //let's imagine this person has a string id attribute with a get method defined

peopleMap.put(person.getId(),person); //adds the person to the list

peopleMap.get("p71"); //assume we're looking for a person which id="p71";
```

The person class could be something in these lines:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String id;
   private int age;

   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }
//other getter/setters and methods you implement
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `Map<String, Person>`?

Comment: Can I use something like a table?

Comment: Indeed, @MickMnemonic, thanks for pointing out my mistake, already edited! :)

Comment: What do you mean, @Sparrow7000? Are you talking about a JTable?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html


A Map looks something like a table where each value (in this case, an object Person) is associated to a key (the Id in this case). You can then easily get the Person by using the key.

Comment: I mean can I use jTable as an object rather than presenter of a table? Is there a data structure like a table in java not to show values in out put but to keep them?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have to*, but I would strongly recommend to define a class. It could look like this:

```
package com.yourcompany.projectname;

public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String familyName;
    public BigDecimal salary;
}
```

then store it in a HashMap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <String, Person> persons = new HasMap <>();

    // define a new person
    Person dady = new Person();
    dady.name = "Tim";
    dady.familyName = "Smith";
    dady.salary = new BigDecimal("1234.56");

    // store it
    persons.put("dady", dady);

    // retrieve it
    Person misterX = persons.get("dady");

    // use it
    System.out.println("MisterX: "+misterX.familyName);
}
```